# html table border

Tags: html

I have the following:

```
        <table class="floatleft" style="margin-right:1em;margin-bottom:1em;border:4px;">
```

Although I have a border around the table, no border shows up. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have specified `border: 4px` which means the same as:

```
border-width: 4px;
border-style: none;
border-color: <the value of the 'color' property>;
```

… because [unspecified values take their initial value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/about.html#shorthand) in shorthand syntax.

Be explicit about the style and colour:

```
border: 4px solid black;
```

(or at least the style, since `none` will stop any border being visible).

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you have a white background and you're not setting a border style and color. Try:

```
<table class="floatleft" style="margin-right:1em;margin-bottom:1em;border:4px solid red;">
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>    
</table>
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/qWLvf/